# Getting Error of Invalid Binary while uploading app to iTune Connect

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect

This is a very common question but though any of the solution I tried is not working. I get the 'invalid binary' status after sometime of 'upload received' status. I have some prediction  as below. can anyone help find the correct one.

1) My last version was 1.1.3, now I want to set version 1.4. Can this be the issue?

2) I have added support of audio playback using AudioToolBox and AVFoundation framework. Can this be related to this issue?

I have uninstall and reinstall the distribution profile. Though it is not working.

Any help will be grateful.

Comment: First of all try to find out the problem by checking issues shared by other developers or compare your issue with others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be receiving an email from Apple explaining the issue. Try to search the reported issue.

Comment: Thanks. I got the mail mentioning that form 1st may 2013 they make compulsion to add launch image supporting iPhone 5 resolution. to add that I need to get new launch image of iphone 5 supported resolution, need to upgrade my xcode and hence need to upgrade my mac lion version. After that my app updated successfully on itunes connect.